# Como conectar dos UI en PyQt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Tengo 2 UI en PyQt que quisiera conectar a travez de un boton de tal forma que al precionar el boton se cierre una y se habra la otra. A continuacion les dejo el codigo en python2.7 de mis UI:
Esta es LlamaGestionAutos.py

```
import sys
from gestionAutos import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MiForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui=Ui_DialogAutos()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonTrabajadores, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.cambiarTrabajadores)

    def cambiarTrabajadores(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp=MiForm()
    myApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Y esta es LlamaGestionTrabajadores.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from gestionTrabajadores import *

class MiForm2(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui=Ui_DialogTrabajadores()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonAutos, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.cambiarAutos)

    def cambiarAutos(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp=MiForm2()
    myApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Que debo poner en los metodos cambiarTrabajadores y cambiarAutos para navegar de una UI a la otra? Gracias y Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu diseño es incorrecto y causa una importación circular, la solucion es rediseñar tu logica. Cada clase (widget) debe tener un unico objetivo y no debe depender de otra clase, y una forma de hacerlo en Qt es usar las señales:

**LlamaGestionAutos.py**

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MiForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui=Ui_DialogAutos()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButtonTrabajadores.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.ui.pushButtonTrabajadores.clicked.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp=MiForm()
    myApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**LlamaGestionTrabajadores.py**

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MiForm2(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui=Ui_DialogTrabajadores()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButtonAutos.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.ui.pushButtonAutos.clicked.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys

    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp=MiForm2()
    myApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.py**

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui

from LlamaGestionAutos import MiForm
from LlamaGestionTrabajadores import MiForm2

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys

    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # create instances
    form1 = MiForm()
    form2 = MiForm2()
    # connections
    form1.clicked.connect(form2.show)
    form2.clicked.connect(form1.show)
    # show widget
    form1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Las señales son uno de los pilares principales de Qt (y de lo que a mi personalmente me atrajo a usar Qt para mis aplicaciones) ya que permite notificar cambios de un elemento sin conocer a quienes se les notifica, a diferencia de otras librerias que usan los callbacks para ello. Para mayor información revisa lo siguiente:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Muchas gracias @eyllanesc me fue de mucha ayuda tu respuesta. Saludos.